# Remove timezone from a moment.js object

Tags: javascript, datetimepicker, momentjs

I'm using [datetimepicker.js](https://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/Functions/#date) and its `date` function returns a [moment.js](http://momentjs.com/) object. It does so with the local UTC offset in it and my original date has a different offset.

My original date:

```
2015-10-01T15:00:00.000Z
```

What I display on the date time picker (`DD-MM HH:mm`):

```
01-10 15:00
```

What I get:

```
2015-10-01T15:40:00+01:00
```

What I want:

```
2015-10-01T15:40:00+00:00
```

Note how I removed the +01 offset at the end.

How can I do this applying it for any local UTC ? This is, without having to manually remove the 01 (as it can be a any other local offset depending on the user location).

```
var momentDate = timePicker.data("DateTimePicker").date();
console.log(momentDate.format());
//this prints  2015-10-01T15:40:00+01:00
```

Comment: Could you please provide some code or a fiddle to demonstrate?  This is pretty easy with moment, but I've no idea which APIs you're using in this datetimepicker control.

Answer (score 83, accepted):

You need to explicitly specify the format.

Try this:

```
momentDate.format('YYYY-MM-DDTHH:mm:ss')
```

this will give the result as

> 2015-10-01T15:40:00

Comment: Does this remove the timezone?

Comment: Yes, exactly @Jordan

Answer (score 42):

It sounds like you are trying to have the user pick a UTC-based date and time.  Therefore, the best way would be to have the picker operate in UTC mode when it creates the moment to begin with.  I'm not familiar with this particular datetimepicker, but assuming somewhere internally it does something like this:

```
var m = moment([year, month-1, day, hour, minute]);
```

Then is should instead do this:

```
var m = moment.utc([year, month-1, day, hour, minute]);
```

*(The variables shown here would be coming from within the picker control.)*

Ideally, the picker control should include a feature to set UTC mode so it can do this internally, when told to by you.

If it doesn't have such a feature, you can still compensate yourself.  Unfortunately, you can't just call `.utc()`, as that would give a different time than the one the user picked.  So, you'll have to compensate by shifting the UTC time by the original moment's offset.

```
var m = // moment value from the picker
var result = moment(m).utc().add(m.utcOffset(), 'm');
```

You can then call `format` or whatever you wish on the result.  Notice that the original moment is *cloned* with `moment(m)`, such that the offset doesn't get lost and the switch to UTC doesn't interfere with the picker's internal behavior.

Also, note that *shifting* like this is generally a hack, and if done wrong can lead to errors.  Here it's ok, because the moment is already in UTC mode when the adjustment is applied.  But as a general solution, shifting should be avoided.  The best option is to have the control placed into UTC mode to begin with.

Comment: For me it only worked if I used `var result = moment(m).add(m.utcOffset(), 'm').utc();`. If utc() is before add, utcOffset doesn't output anything

Comment: @TheFullResolution - I think maybe you did `m.utc().add...` instead of `moment(m).utc().add...`

Answer (score 16):

Try this:

```js
let str = '2015-10-01T15:40+01:00';
let moment = moment(str).utcOffset(str)
console.log(moment.format('DD/MM/YYYY HH:mm'))
```

```html
<script src="https://momentjs.com/downloads/moment.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 12):

This worked for me:

```
let date = "2017-02-01 15:20:00.00";
let pattern = "YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss.SS"
let d = moment(date, pattern).utc(false);
```

It will still say that it considered the timezone, but I find that it doesn't.

```
LOG: 'ParseDateStr::2017-2-1 15:20:00.0000000
ParsedDate::Wed Feb 01 2017 15:20:00 GMT+0100 (Central European Standard Time)'
```

Normally, with just `moment(date, pattern)` it would parse as `16:20:00`

Answer (score 1):

Not a clean solution but you could do

```
momentDate.format('YYYY-MM-DDTHH:mm:ss') + '00:00';
```

This would remove the timezone and then append the '00:00' part back in. This is to extend Matt's answer.

Which would give you

> 2015-10-01T15:40:00+00:00